# Regular expression that negates white space, forward slashes, and backward slashes

Tags: c#, regex

I have written a regex that is supposed to match a string without white space, forward, or backward slashes. Problem is, I'm getting an "unterminated set" error.

My regex:

```
Regex checkForSpace = new Regex("^[^\\s\\/\\]+$");
```

It was working as it was supposed to before I added the backslash snippet, now I get the error. Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. This is my first significant experience with regular expressions.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're accidentally escaping the closing `]` in the regex.

Try this:

```
                Regex       C# string
White space     \s          "\\s"
Backslash       \\          "\\\\"
Slash           /           "/"
                \s\\/       "\\s\\\\/"
```

```cs
Regex checkForSpace = new Regex("^[^\\s\\\\/]+$");
```

Answer (score 6):

you are running into backslash escaping. Both the regex and the C# string need it.  To avoid the C# needing it, put the @ symbol in.

try doing it like  (with the @ at the beginning of the string)

```
new Regex(@"^[^\s/\\]+$");
```

Comment: +1, but to avoid confusion you should refer to the `@"…"` style as *verbatim string literals* or just *verbatim strings* [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)